# Techniques for Fourier Transforms in Probability Theory

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, reference-request, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

***Question:* What are the typical methods used to compute Fourier transforms for probability type integrals?**

There are so many different techniques for integration, but since probability integrals seem to be mostly of a certain type (eg. they concern algebraic, exponential, and special functions) I figure there should probably be some methods that are used over and over again. What are they?

---

Note: I have had first courses on complex analysis, harmonic analysis and probability theory. I am looking for a collection of techniques to learn about so I can tackle more and more of these types of integrals on my own. A big picture overview would be nice too.

As it stands now, I just eventually give up and ask on here, but I would like to sort of get an idea of which techniques to try, so I can extend the time it takes to give up and have some general idea about where the answers I receive here fit.

Comment: I hope I don't get roasted...this is a serious question and I really have nobody to ask.

Comment: It is very good question in my opinion. I also hope it does not get roasted.

Comment: What do they need a 'special' treatment ?.

Comment: @TheDude The complex analysis book by Priestley has a chapter on fourier transforms with examples drawn from probability theory, although I haven't personally studied from that book. Can I ask if you've found study of complex analysis and/or harmonic analysis helpful for probability theory? What books would you recommend? (upper undergraduate/beginning graduate). Especially harmonic/fourier analysis books always seem geared towards physics and differential equations but my focus is on probability theory.

Comment: This may be a good question for a reference request on mathoverflow.com